# How to add "member" to MainWindow class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

So i have started to learn Qt, and i got hold of Qt5 C++ GUI Programming Cookbook. I wanted to make a simple video converter, and there is a example on how to do it in the book.

But executing the code from the book gives me an error:

```
'Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'filePath'
     ui->filePath->setText(fileName);
         ^
```

So i guess i have to add filePath to the MainWindow, but since im new to Qt and C++ i dont know exactly how to do that.

Here is mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QDebug>
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QProcess* process;
    QString outputText;
    QString fileName;
    QString outputFileName;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void processStarted();
    void readyReadStandardOutput();
    void processFinished();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    process = new QProcess(this);
    connect(process, SIGNAL(started()), this,
    SLOT(processStarted()));
    connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),
    this,SLOT(readyReadStandardOutput()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this,
    SLOT(processFinished()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "OpenVideo", "", "Video Files (*.avi *.mp4 *.mov)");
    ui->filePath->setText(fileName);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString ffmpeg = "C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
    QStringList arguments;
    fileName = ui->filePath->text();
    if (fileName != "")
    {
        QFileInfo fileInfo = QFile(fileName);
        outputFileName = fileInfo.patch() + "/" + fileInfo.completeBaseName();

        if (QFile::exists(fileName))
        {
            //0-AVI
            //1-MP4
            //2-MOV
            int format = ui -> fileFormat-> currentIndex();
            if (format ==0)
            {
                outputFileName += ".avi";
            }
            else if (format ==1)
            {
                outputFileName += ".mp4";
            }
            else if (format ==2)
            {
                outputFileName += ".mov";
            }
            qDebug()<<outputFileName<<format;
            arguments<< "-i"<<fileName<<outputFileName;
            qDebug()<<arguments;

            process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
            process->start(ffmpeg,arguments);
         }
         else
         {
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"Failed", "Failed to open video file.");
         }
      else
      {
           QMessageBox::warning(this,"Failed", "Failed to open video file.");
      }

    }
}
void MainWindow::processStarted()
{
qDebug() << "Process started.";
ui->browseButton->setEnabled(false);
ui->fileFormat->setEditable(false);
ui->convertButton->setEnabled(false);
}
void MainWindow::readyReadStandardOutput()
{
outputText += process->readAllStandardOutput();
ui->outputDisplay->setText(outputText);
ui->outputDisplay->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(ui->outputDisplay->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());
}
void MainWindow::processFinished()
{
qDebug() << "Process finished.";
if (QFile::exists(outputFileName))
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Success", "Videosuccessfully converted.");
}
else
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Failed", "Failed to convertvideo.");
}
ui->browseButton->setEnabled(true);
ui->fileFormat->setEditable(true);
```

And mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>404</width>
    <height>334</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>281</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Browse</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>371</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>AVI</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>MP4</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>MOV</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>371</width>
      <height>141</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>250</y>
      <width>371</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Convert</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>404</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the `.ui` file. You need to open Designer, click in your `filePath`, and change its name to `filePath`. Currently, it is `textEdit`.

All visual controls that you put on the `.ui` file via the Designer application should match the names you are using in the C++ code to access them.

Comment: Thank you, but im left with two more errors:
<pre>    'class QFileInfo' has no member named 'patch'
         outputFileName = fileInfo.patch() + "/" + fileInfo.completeBaseName();
                                   ^     <code>
and 
           'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'fileFormat'
             int format = ui -> fileFormat-> currentIndex();
                                ^

Comment: because it's path() and not patch(), and because you forgot to do the same thing I asked for the textField for the fileFormat in the ui file.